# convert decimal based &#code to unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

in python 3, I have JSON string like

```
{
  "tag" : "&#1605;&#1608;",
  "id" : 1
}
```

I use `json.loads` method, but it doesn't convert 
how can I convert it to Unicode string and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the HTML entity and replace it with its Unicode character:

```
import json
import re

raw_data = '''\
{
  "tag" : "&#1605;&#1608;",
  "id" : 1
}
'''

data = json.loads(raw_data)
data['tag'] = re.sub(r'&#(\d+);',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))),data['tag'])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'tag': 'مو', 'id': 1}
```

A better solution if possible is to write the JSON correctly to begin with, which would be either of:

```
option1 = json.dumps(data)
option2 = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
print(option1)
print(option2)
```

Output:

```
{"tag": "\u0645\u0648", "id": 1}
{"tag": "مو", "id": 1}
```